# Customize neutral button in Alert Dialog Box

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

I am using an Alert Dialog box, I would like to place the Neutral button in the position of Text "Testing Material Design", as shown in the attached image. Basically, I would like to place the neutral button, in the same place as the "Testing Material Design," however, by default, the Android is putting the Neutral button the present position. Any guidance, suggestions, or help of how to achieve this would be highly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can't you change the layout in the XML?

Comment: No Sacha, that's because I am not using XML, I am just adding the Positive, Negative and Neutral buttons, using Java code like:
.setPositiveButton("Positive", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

Comment: Remove your NEUTRAL button here and use a CustomLayout for your Dialog. In your CustomLayout, place a NEUTRAL button where ever you want.

Comment: I would like to do it via Java code, any ideas?